# I can not get Openshift oc command line tool 32 bit version for linux (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, openshift, redhat, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

On project overview page of Openshift v3 (developer preview) by going to help->Command Line Tools , it only shows 64 bit version for linux but not 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `oc` tool directly from the OpenShift Origin Git Repo: https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/tag/v1.2.2

They provide a 32-bit client for linux there!

Comment: Thanks Will I found it.